# how can I add lock screen interacting widgets in android pie

Tags: android, widget, lockscreen, android-9.0-pie

I want to access my apps functions directly from the lock screen but I can't, it is only showing the app icon without the ability to click it unless screen unlocked,i am using my mobile with android 9 as emulator .
is there any way to solve it,thanks

Answer (score 0):

as I found from Android developer website,it is not possible after version 5 as below

"The widget Category attribute declares whether your App Widget can be displayed on the home screen (home_screen), the lock screen (key guard), or both. Only Android versions lower than 5.0 support lock-screen widgets. For Android 5.0 and higher, only home_screen is valid."